# Understanding the Scala Map object when mapping to the head of a list

Tags: scala, scala-collections, implicit, scala-implicits

Hi I have the following data and want to map it to the first item in the second parameter. So for:

```
1 -> List((1,11))
1 -> List((1,1), (1,111))
```

I want:

```
(1,11)
(1,1)
```

When this data is in an RDD I can do the following:

```
scala> val m = sc.parallelize(Seq(11 -> List((1,11)), 1 -> List((1,1),(1,111))))
m: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, List[(Int, Int)])] = ParallelCollectionRDD[198] at parallelize at <console>:47

scala> m.map(_._2.head).collect.foreach(println)
(1,11)
(1,1)
```

However, when it is in a Map object (result of a groupBy) I get the following:

```
scala> val m = Map(11 -> List((1,11)), 1 -> List((1,1)))
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[(Int, Int)]] = Map(11 -> List((1,11)), 1 -> List((1,1), (1,111)))

scala> m.map(_._2.head)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1)
```

When I map to the whole list I get what I would expect, but not when I call head on it

```
scala> m.map(_._2)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[List[(Int, Int)]] = List(List((1,11)), List((1,1), (1,111)))
```

I can also get the result I want if I do either of the following:

```
scala> m.map(_._2).map(_.head)
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[(Int, Int)] = List((1,11), (1,1))

scala> m.values.map(_.head)
res5: Iterable[(Int, Int)] = List((1,11), (1,1))
```

Could someone explain please what is going on here?

Comment: you can also do `m.toSeq.map(_._2.head)` to get the desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map operation on a `scala.collection.immutable.Map` behave differently depending on the return type of the map operation.

**When the return type if of Type Tuple2[T,P]**:

the output of the Map operation results in an another `Map` with the first element of the tuple `_1` as the key and the second element `_2` as the value.

for example

```
scala> m.map(_ => 10 -> 1)
res14: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(10 -> 1) // note the return type is Map.
```

**When the return type is anything other than Tuple2**:

when the return type is anything other than Tuple2 then output of the map operation is a list.

```
scala> m.map(_ => 10 )
res15: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Int] = List(10, 10) // note that the return type now is a List.
```

so with the above established fact, for a `Map` of value `Map(11 -> List((1,11)), 1 -> List((1,1)))` the operation `m.map(_._2.head)` produces Tuple2 values `(1, 11)` and `(1,1)`. since the first value (`_1`) of each Tuple2 item is 1 (i.e. the key of each value is 1), the `(1,1)` overwrites `(1,11)` and we end up with a single value of `(1,1)`.

In other cases the map operation doesnt return types of Tuple2 and hence it results in `List` type instead of `Map`types hence the difference is results.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit tricky and depends on the implicit parameter CanBuildFrom of the map. Depending the output type of your function f it will be able to build one structure or the other (it will be built by the implicit CanBuildFrom).

```
m.map(_._2.head) // The passed function retrieves a pair (Int, Int)
```

There is a implicit CanBuildFrom from (A, A) to Map[A,A], that object is passed to your map implicitly, that's why in that case the the returned object is Map[Int, Int]

On the other case you have

```
m.map(_._2) // The passed function retrieves a List[(Int, Int)]
```

The implicit CanBuildFrom for List[A] will build a Iterable[A], in this case from List[(Int, Int)] to Iterable[(Int, Int)]